# How to Intercept connection requests?

Tags: .net, network-programming

I'm working on an app that needs to intercept when a program tries to connect to an specified IP address and redirects it to another IP.

Is this possible?

I'm using .net for this.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [EasyHook project](http://www.codeplex.com/easyhook) to hook the [connect function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737625(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It might not fit the bill, but you could use the "hosts" file.
("hosts" file will only work for this purpose if the program is not connecting by IP address, but a host name)